# How do I get the Commands line in the absolute bottom of the screen

Tags: neovim, plugin-airline, iterm2

I'm setting up neovim and I can't seem to use the screen fully. This is how the terminal looks when I open neovim in either Terminal App, iTerm 2 or Alacrity.

There is a whole empty like below where commands go. How do I make this thing go so I can get more space to look at the code.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably one of two things:

1. The `cmdheight` setting is `2` or higher; you can check the current value with `:set cmdheight?`, and set it to the default of `1` with `:set cmdheight=1`. There's something in your vimrc or a plugin changing from the default, you can use `:verbose set cmdheight?` to see where it was last set.
2. The terminal screen isn't quite big enough to fit an entire row of characters; since terminals are grid-based this means there may be some padding if the screen size isn't an exact multitude of the font size. I'm not entirely sure how to check this, but if you fill up your screen outside of Vim you should see the same issue. Judging from your screenshot I'd guess it's *probably* the first issue though.